# How to set the delay between update queries in Mysql so that every query get executed succesfully?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to execute mulitple UPDATE queries for different parameters using a for loop. Now the problem is that whenever I do it, only my last query gets executed, all the previous queries seem to be skipped.

```
foreach ($flagSet as $controlDoc => $controlFlag)
{
    for ($t = 0; $t < count($controlFlag); $t++)
    {
        $userLevel = "controller";
        $docFlag = 1;
        $postfix = "created";
        $createDoc->updateFlags($controlFlag[$t], $docFlag, $controlDoc, $postfix, $userLevel);
        $docFlag = 2;
        $postfix = "midlevel";
        $createDoc->updateFlags($controlFlag[$t], $docFlag, $controlDoc, $postfix, $userLevel);
    }
}
```

The called function

```
$query = "UPDATE tbl_docuserstatus SET";

if($flag != "")
{
    $query .= " docseeflag_" . $postfix . " = '" . $flag . "'";
}

$query .= " WHERE doc_id = '" . $doc_id . "' AND user_id = '" . $user_id . "'";

if($userLevel == "midlevel")
{
    $query .= " AND doc_midlvluser = '1'";
}
elseif ($userLevel == "finalLevel")
{
    $query .= " AND doc_finallvluser = '1'";
}
elseif ($userLevel == "creator")
{
    $query .= " AND doc_creator = '1'";
}
elseif ($userLevel == "controller")
{
    $query .= " AND doc_controller = '1'";
}
elseif ($docarchive == 1)
{
    $query .= " AND doc_controller = '1'";
}
```

So could some one tell me, how to set the delay between update queries in Mysql so that every query get executed succesfully?

Comment: PHP's MySQL adapters are all synchronous by default.  They need to wait for MySQL to actually execute the command given before returning.  You probably don't have a timing issue here.  Have you made sure that the queries are actually being sent to the server?

Comment: change syntax to `UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY`

Comment: It is driving me crazy :). There must still be thousends of bad beginner tutorials out there otherwise such coding practices would not exist anymore... good coding practices lead to less errors because of better readability of the code. In your code, you might have found the errors already. I'm going to reformat your code for better readability.

Comment: @Markus, Yes I Was Wrong In My coding Part.. Thanks N e Ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to put a delay in, there should be some other error. (like @Charles said in the comment).

What you should do, and all I can advice I think with current code, is echo all the queries you are performing, and verify that they are correct. Do this not only by looking at them, but execute them in a mysql client (commandline, phpmyadmin, etc).

If they do execute correctly, check if your PHP code runs all the queries at the rigth moment: does it actually execute the query-strings you are building?

Comment: Yes I Was Wrong In My coding Part.. Thanks N e Ways